# Render queue error in BeginRender[backoffice/Index:pagelink]: 64001 org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: 64001

Tags: spring-boot, tapestry

I'm migrating from Tapestry 5.2.4 to 5.3.2 in order to be compatible with spring 5.
But when i chaned the version in the pom.xml and run my code it's work. but when i launch the site web i have an issue with one page. i i have already seen the breaking change between the two version here https://tapestry.apache.org/release-notes-53.html but nothing to change on my code.

```
<html t:type="BackOfficeLayout" environement="getEnvironement()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd" xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
 <div id="navbarsign" class="navbar">

        <ul class="k-navbar" role="menubar">
            <li class="${isActive('index')}" ><a href="${buildUrl('/index')}">test3 </a></li>
            <li>
                <a class="hasdropdown">test2 </a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="${isActive('adminPage')}" >
                        <t:pagelink page="backoffice/adminPage" context="'create'" >admin page</t:pagelink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="${isActive('searchCreditor')}" ><a href="${buildUrl('/test')}">test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

.
.
.

this the error i have:

```
[ERROR] (RenderQueueImpl.java:run:79) Render queue error in BeginRender[backoffice/Index:pagelink]: 64001
```

org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: 64001
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$BeginRenderPhase.render(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderQueueImpl.render(PageRenderQueueImpl.java:124)
    at $PageRenderQueue_4ae74bbe12c.render(Unknown Source)
    at $PageRenderQueue_4ae74bbe12b.render(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MarkupRendererTerminator.renderMarkup(MarkupRendererTerminator.java:37)
    at net.atos.kawwaportal.components.services.KawwaPortalComponentsModule$1.renderMarkup(KawwaPortalComponentsModule.java:89)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$30.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1979)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$29.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1963)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at net.atos.kawwaportal.components.services.KawwaPortalComponentsModule$2.renderMarkup(KawwaPortalComponentsModule.java:102)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$28.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1945)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$27.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1930)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$26.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1916)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.js.JSModule$1.renderMarkup(JSModule.java:40)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$25.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1898)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$24.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1879)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe130.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at $MarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe12a.renderMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageMarkupRendererImpl.renderPageMarkup(PageMarkupRendererImpl.java:47)
    at $PageMarkupRenderer_4ae74bbe128.renderPageMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageResponseRendererImpl.renderPageResponse(PageResponseRendererImpl.java:67)
    at $PageResponseRenderer_4ae74bbe0ca.renderPageResponse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderRequestHandlerImpl.handle(PageRenderRequestHandlerImpl.java:64)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$37.handle(TapestryModule.java:2207)
    at $PageRenderRequestHandler_4ae74bbe0cc.handle(Unknown Source)
    at $PageRenderRequestHandler_4ae74bbe0c6.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handlePageRender(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:48)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handlePageRender(InitializeActivePageName.java:47)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_4ae74bbe0c7.handlePageRender(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_4ae74bbe089.handlePageRender(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderDispatcher.dispatch(PageRenderDispatcher.java:45)
    at $Dispatcher_4ae74bbe08c.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at $Dispatcher_4ae74bbe085.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:302)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26)
    at $RequestHandler_4ae74bbe086.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:902)
    at $RequestHandler_4ae74bbe086.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:892)
    at $RequestHandler_4ae74bbe086.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    at $RequestHandler_4ae74bbe086.service(Unknown Source)
    at $RequestHandler_4ae74bbe079.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:253)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_4ae74bbe07b.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.service(AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.java:26)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_4ae74bbe07b.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:44)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_4ae74bbe07b.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_4ae74bbe077.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_4ae74bbe07b.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:852)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_4ae74bbe07b.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_4ae74bbe074.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: 64001
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl.createInstantiatorForClass(ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl.getInstantiator(ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl.java:216)
    at $ComponentInstantiatorSource_4ae74bbe0a6.getInstantiator(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentModelSourceImpl.getModel(ComponentModelSourceImpl.java:34)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentModelSourceImpl.getPageModel(ComponentModelSourceImpl.java:39)
    at $ComponentModelSource_4ae74bbe0a5.getPageModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MetaDataLocatorImpl$2.valueForKey(MetaDataLocatorImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MetaDataLocatorImpl.getSymbolExpandedValueFromCache(MetaDataLocatorImpl.java:119)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MetaDataLocatorImpl.findMeta(MetaDataLocatorImpl.java:99)
    at $MetaDataLocator_4ae74bbe09c.findMeta(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestSecurityManagerImpl.isSecure(RequestSecurityManagerImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestSecurityManagerImpl.checkPageSecurity(RequestSecurityManagerImpl.java:114)
    at $RequestSecurityManager_4ae74bbe099.checkPageSecurity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventLinkEncoderImpl.createPageRenderLink(ComponentEventLinkEncoderImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.linktransform.LinkTransformerInterceptor.createPageRenderLink(LinkTransformerInterceptor.java:50)
    at $ComponentEventLinkEncoder_4ae74bbe08b.createPageRenderLink(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.LinkSourceImpl.createPageRenderLink(LinkSourceImpl.java:119)
    at $LinkSource_4ae74bbe0f0.createPageRenderLink(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.createPageRenderLink(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:111)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.createPageLink(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.InternalComponentResourcesImpl.createPageLink(InternalComponentResourcesImpl.java:221)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.PageLink.beginRender(PageLink.java:57)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.PageLink.beginRender(PageLink.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$BeginRenderPhase.invokeComponent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:202)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:143)
    ... 142 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64001
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:2015)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:469)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.PlasticInternalUtils.convertBytecodeToClassNode(PlasticInternalUtils.java:431)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.PlasticClassPool.constructClassNodeFromBytecode(PlasticClassPool.java:475)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.PlasticClassPool.getPlasticClassTransformation(PlasticClassPool.java:425)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.PlasticClassPool.loadAndTransformClass(PlasticClassPool.java:346)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.PlasticClassLoader.loadClass(PlasticClassLoader.java:38)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.PlasticClassPool.getClassInstantiator(PlasticClassPool.java:510)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.PlasticManager.getClassInstantiator(PlasticManager.java:189)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl$2.invoke(ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl.java:234)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl$2.invoke(ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    ... 169 common frames omitted

Comment: Somehow related to an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException shown in the stack trace - 64k off by one... but not sure what this tells us. Have you tried this against a more recent version of Tapestry as well? The latest release is 5.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `<t:PageLink page="backoffice/adminPage" context="literal:create">`